# On form submit trigger expired?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, eventtrigger

this is the first time I'm using triggers with Google App Scripts and I was really  delighted about the possibility to send individualised mails to users who submit a form. But...

I created a form and an App Script from a sheet with the **on form submit trigger**. I gave all the permissions and tested it and everything worked fine. Well... **two weeks later** we posted the link to the form. I expected everything to work fine, since I didn't read anything about an expiry date or something like that for triggers. But after a while - some users already submitted the form I realised the script didn't run (there were no automated Mails send). I tested it by submitting the form by myself - it didn't work. **I checked all permissions and the trigger** - everything looked fine. I decided to **delete the trigger and create it again** - exactly the same trigger (since there are not a lot of different options I'm pretty sure it's exactly all the same). I didn't have to give any new permissions or anything. I submitted the form and **it worked**!!! So my question is:

**Is the any expiry date for triggers?**

**Does anybody have a clue for other possible reasons?**

**Does anybody out there had this problem already?**

I hope there is an easy explanation.

Thank you*

Comment: View> Executions >Uncheck "Ran as me"... See what happened

Comment: The On Form Submit trigger for Google Forms has a long history of silently failing.    The problem has been reported to Google on the Issue Tracker.  See link: [On Form Submit Fails](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763929)  Please "star" the issue, and leave a comment if you'd like to help promote a solution.  I don't know of any "work around" or fix for the problem that can be implemented.

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood for your reply!****Stars for your posts on issuetracker.

I also [posted this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116735203) before on issuetracker, sorry I didn't see yours before.

As recommended I'll also follow [this post on issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113346913) for the problem, that the trigger expires.